# Windows 7 shows a drive as full in summary but i can't see what's taking up all the space

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

Sorry i'm not too computer savy and i'm looking for some help, if someone would be so kind.
My D drive is saying i only have 166mb free of 703GB. I have pretty much cleared off all my files from there but the space keeps getting lower and lower, the total file usage on the drive is 11.7GB, i have no idea what could be taking up all that space. Any ideas on how to fix this would be great!

Comment: Did you check your recyclebin? Deleting often moves the files there and thus technically not removing them.

Comment: Yup it's empty :-) it's the first thing i do after deleting stuff.

Answer (score 0):

One nice tool that visually shows windows directories by their size is [spacesniffer.](http://www.uderzo.it/main_products/space_sniffer/)
Directories with large files are shown as relatively larger blocks.